# NextLink Dynamic Route Not Working When In Dynamic Route

Tags: reactjs, next.js, next-link

I have an dynamic route which is `sitename.com/[username]`
When I navigate from `sitename.com/account` to `sitename.com/[username]` (for example when I am in `/account` page, I click an username which is `abdulkadirkg`) it is working. But if I am in `sitename.com/abdulkadirkg` and I click another username which is `sitename.com/otherusername` although the link has changed it doesn't work. My code is here;

```
<NextLink href={{pathname:"/[username]",query:{username:subscriber.userName}}} >
    <Typography variant="subtitle2" noWrap>
        {firstName} {lastName}
    </Typography>
</NextLink>
```

I also tried this;

```
 <NextLink href={PATH+subscriber.userName} >
```

Full Code (`[username].js`);

```
export default function UserProfile({username}) {
    const router = useRouter();
    const [user, setUser] = useState({});
    const [isSameUser,setIsSameUser] = useState(false);
    if (username === undefined) username = router.query.username;
    const authenticatedUser = useAuth();
    useEffect(() => {
        async function fetchData() {
            await axios.get("/User/GetProfileByUserName/" + username).then(response => {
                setUser(response.data.data);
            }).catch(err => enqueueSnackbar(err.message, {variant: 'error'}))
        }
        fetchData();
        setIsSameUser(username === authenticatedUser.user.userName);
    }, [])
    return (
        <Page title="User: Profile">
            <Container maxWidth={themeStretch ? false : 'lg'}>
                <HeaderBreadcrumbs
                    heading="Profile"
                />
                <Card>
                    <ProfileCover user={user}/>
                </Card>
            </Container>
        </Page>
    );
}
```

in `ProfileSubscribers.js`;

```
 <NextLink href={PATH+subscriber.userName} >
```

Comment: You likely need to use an `useEffect` hook to "listen" for changes on the dynamic part of your route path so it can handle the change or whatever it needs to do with the new value.

Comment: I think that way is not best practice. But if I can't handle it, I will do that way. @DrewReese

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by "not best practice" when that is exactly what `useEffect` hook is for, issuing side-effects as a response to some external change. `useEffect` hook with appropriate dependency is roughly equivalent to `componentDidUpdate` lifecycle method from class components. Perhaps it would be helpful to share an example for what needs to "respond" to this dynamic route changing.

Comment: @DrewReese it's just my opinion. I didn't say "it is wrong". Thank you for your reply. I just want to make some more research before apply your solution.

Comment: No worries, I was curious why. Thanks for the component code example. I can see clearly now that `username` is obviously, and should be, a dependency for the `useEffect` hook fetching data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `username` value from the route query is referenced in the `useEffect` fetching user data, it should be added to the `useEffect` hook's dependency array so when `username` value changes `fetchData` is called again with the new value.

```
export default function UserProfile({ username }) {
  const router = useRouter();
  const [user, setUser] = useState({});
  const [isSameUser, setIsSameUser] = useState(false);

  if (username === undefined) username = router.query.username;

  const authenticatedUser = useAuth();

  useEffect(() => {
    async function fetchData() {
      await axios.get("/User/GetProfileByUserName/" + username)
        .then(response => {
          setUser(response.data.data);
        })
        .catch(err => enqueueSnackbar(err.message, { variant: 'error' }));
    }
    fetchData();
    setIsSameUser(username === authenticatedUser.user.userName);
  }, [username]);

  return (
    <Page title="User: Profile">
      <Container maxWidth={themeStretch ? false : 'lg'}>
        <HeaderBreadcrumbs heading="Profile" />
        <Card>
          <ProfileCover user={user} />
        </Card>
      </Container>
    </Page>
  );
}
```